# spring boot (jetty) catch upload error (file too big)

Tags: file-upload, spring-boot, jetty

I am trying to handle the situation when the uploaded file is too large.
Setting max file size to unlimited is not an option.
As far as i see the problem is that the exception is thrown outside spring - in this case in jetty

I did some googling, and the answers suggest i should check for MultipartException .

I don't see this exception being thrown at all.

So in general i am banging my head here. How do i catch this exception in order to display a nice error ?

Thank you.

**Edit :**
This smells like a bug.
MultipartException IS thrown when using tomcat instead of jetty !
My code is working fine with tomcat.

I am still interested to make it work with jetty though.
**End edit**

This is the exception thrown (jetty):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multipart Mime part file exceeds max filesize
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser$MultiPart.write(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:111) ~[jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.parse(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:681) ~[jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.getParts(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:400) ~[jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2146) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractMultipartParameters(Request.java:386) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractContentParameters(Request.java:309) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractParameters(Request.java:257) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameter(Request.java:826) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:194) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:125) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:65) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) [jetty-security-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544) [jetty-io-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
```

Comment: what's the full package to the `MultipartException` that you are encountering on tomcat? (as there no such exception in the servlet or jee specs)

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think this may be a bug in Jetty. With Tomcat, a `MultipartException` is thrown by Spring MVC from within `DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart`. This method accesses all of the request's parts. Tomcat throws an exception when one of the parts is too big, triggering the `MultipartException`. Jetty, on the other hand, allows Spring MVC to retrieve all of the request parts, even when one of them exceeds the maximum size. It then fails later on when a second attempt is made to access the request's parts but it's too late for Spring MVC to throw a MultipartException.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt the exception is : nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exc..

Comment: Opened bug https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/81 for the MultipartException piece

Comment: @AndyWilkinson added another, more specific bug, for your discovery about retreiving the rest of the rest of parts after an error - https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/82